# Error when using foundation.core.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am trying to put some dropdown buttons on my site (doc : http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/dropdown.html). I got it to work by just putting `foundation.min.js` on my page but that includes all of the plugins and is pretty large. I am trying to set it up by loading individual plugins according to the documentation : http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html.

I am loading `foundation.core.js` and after that I'm also loading the keyboard util, box util, and dropdown plugin.

This is the error that I get..

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_init' of undefined
```

This error is occuring on line 245 of foundation.core.js. It happens even when I just load jQuery and `foundation.core.js` with no other Foundation files.

Anyone have any ideas as to what is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you load `foundation.core.js` at first ?

Comment: Yep I did. Loading core, then keyboard util, box util, and finally dropdown.

Comment: Do you have error in development console tool ? And network tab ?

Comment: Yep, error in the console is what I put in my original post. Not getting any errors in network tab.

Comment: Do you initialize your application with `$(document).foundation();` ?

Comment: Yes, I am doing that.

Comment: So can you put your code please

Comment: more info here: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/7446 and https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/7327

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting `foundation.util.mediaQuery` after `foundation.core`. The two scripts have a co-dependency.